How generate a runnable jar increasing the default heap space?
The switch -Xmx512M works to me in a JAVA 32 bits when I run a program within the eclipse, for example.
But I want to do this when I generate a runnable jar file, that runs with a double click. But the runnable jar file runs always with the default heap space 64M.
Someone knows how can I increase the heap space for a runnable jar file?

There is, in principle, a separation between Java classes and the JVM on which they run.  A JAR packages classes and resources, but it is, in principle, JVM-agnostic.  The JAR file format therefore does not provide a way to specify VM arguments, which are (again, in principle) JVM-specific.

The dupe target is old, but the situation is unchanged since then.
